# Java String manipulation: Time and Space complexity using StringBuilder

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was recently interviewed at a XXX company and was asked to write a code to reverse the words in the input.

Input: "My name is Joe"

Output: "yM eman si eoJ"

I wrote below code which compiled and run successfully with all test cases passed.

Below is my code (Programming language used - Java):

```
 public String reverseWords(String s) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      s += ' ';
      for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
           if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' && s.charAt(i-1) != ' ') {
                if (sb.length()>0) sb.append(' ');
                for (int j = i-1; j >= 0 && s.charAt(j) != ' '; j--) sb.append(s.charAt(j));
           }
      }
      return sb.toString();
 }
```

Interviewer then asked with Time and Space complexity of the code to which I said: Space complexity looks O(N) (where N is number of characters in input) and Time complexity is Quadratic. The interviewer did not seem satisfied.

What would be the time and space complexity of the above code? Also, feedback with any better approach would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think the time complexity is quadratic? Isn’t is n + n = 2n which is nothing but n

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a homework question

Comment: @smac89 How this is a homework? I gave you the reference of how I came up with this concern.

Comment: @TheRoy I thought 'quadratic' due to the append function we use in inner 'for' loop everytime we get a new word. I thought append does not take constant time.

Comment: The outer loop is _O(n)_. The inner loop runs at most `n/2` times (once for each space encountered), but is limited to characters between spaces, so it processes at most _O(n)_ characters *in total*, so it is _O(n)_ too (in total). Just because it's inside the outer loop, doesn't mean you multiply complexity here, so overall performance is just _O(n)_.

Comment: Understandable, but this kind of question is not really well suited for SO. You can try something like cs.stackexchange.com or any other exchange sites that discuss time complexity. See this post if you have questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252490/algorithm-time-complexity-question-which-qa-shall-i-post-it-to/252493